# Help with architechting the flow of an Invite page

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design

I'm implementing an invite page where users can log onto their email account and import contacts from their address book.  My question is relating to the database design for this.  I want to store all the emails for each user that invites, so that on subsequent visits to the invite, they won't have to log in.  This will also allow me to give friend recommendations etc.

I was thinking of creating a new table called contacts with the fields userid, contantname, contactemail.  I realize that many users may have the same contact, so I'm wondering if it's good db design to store the contactname and contactemail on a separate table, or if it's okay in this case to keep them in the same table.

I'm also curious to know how others have architected the whole invite flow.  IN mine for example, for each contact that already exists in the system, I'll prompt the user to follow, and if the contact is not in system, I'll prompt the user to invite them. When the invited user signs up, the user and invited user will automatically follow each other, and the entry will get deleted from the contacts db.  In the case where the contact exists for multiple users, once that contact accepts the invitation from one user, I'll display the other users as recommendations for following.  Does this sound okay, or is there a better approach to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What attribute or set of attributes is "contact name" functionally dependent upon in your domain?  Is it on userid or contactemail?
Answer that and you answer your question.  I have the following scenario for you to consider:

Let's say there's a contactemail: janedoe@example.com

In my address book, her contact name is "Jane Doe"

In John Doe's address book, it's "Stupid Kid Sister"

In Jane Doe's email service, it's "Jane Mary Doe".

If you already have knowlege of "Jane Mary Doe" before I or John Doe invite Jane, then you have your answer; contactname is functionally dependent on contactemail.  If you don't, you have your answer: it would never be appropriate for me to see, or my invite email to Jane, through some path dependent event, to address "Stupid Kid Sister"; contactname is functionally dependent on userid and contactemail.

Comment: I revised my db so that all imported contacts would go into the users table (and a status field to indicate if the user has registered or not).  Then a contacts table with userid, contactid (which is a user in the user table either registered or not).  Now with your scenario, I think I may have to add name in the contacts table so it's personal to each user.